# How to modify enum by void method? <Java>

Tags: java, methods, enums, void

My enum is days of the week. I want to write method prevDay(), which will modify each

```
Day day
```

type to make it equal

```
Day.MON
```

I get an error when I call the following code:

ERROR - left hand side of assignment must be a variable.

```
public enum Day {

    MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN;

    public static main(String[] args){
         Day d= Day.TUE;
         d.prevDay();
    }
    public void prevDay(){
        this=Day.MON;
    }

}
```

But if I call:

```
public enum Day{
MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN;


     public static main(String[] args){
          Day d= Day.TUE;
          d=d.prevDay();// if I change this line to: "d.prevDay() "
     }                  // will day also be modified?

     public Day prevDay(){
          return Day.MON;
     }
}
```

There is no error. Why?

Comment: What language is this?  What does the error tell you?  How are you calling the method?

Comment: Give me -4000 downvote or tell me what i have to modify in my question to make it better because I don't know.

Comment: (1) Originally you didn't specify the error, you've at least somewhat corrected that.  (2) You still don't specify what *language* this is.  (3) It seems *very unlikely* that `return=Day.MON;` runs without error, I've never seen that syntax before.  (4) What are you trying to accomplish and why?  Take care to specify what you're talking about and what you're asking.  If your question isn't important enough to you to merit *your* attention, it's unlikely to merit *our* attention.

Answer (score 0):

i did a little research for you and found the following:

http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/javainsel9/javainsel_09_004.htm#mjb51623ea831884c57b143981630b06fb

see Listing 9.26

can you try to use a this.Day instead of a simple this?